# Excel VBA: Variants in Array Variables

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, types, variant

A question on variants.  Im aware that variants in Excel vba are both the default data type and also inefficient (from the viewpoint of overuse in large apps).  However, I regularly use them for storing data in arrays that have multiple data types.  A current project I am working on is essentially a task that requires massive optimistaion of very poor code (c.7000 lines)- and it got me thinking; is there a way around this?

To explain; the code frequently stores data in array variables.  So consider a dataset of 10 columns by 10000.  The columns are multiple different data types (string, double, integers, dates,etc).  Assuming I want to store these in an array, I would usually;

```
dim myDataSet(10,10000) as variant
```

But, my knowledge says that this will be really inefficient with the code evaluating each item to determine what data type it is (when in practise I know what Im expecting).  Plus, I lose the control that dimensioning individual data types gives me.  So, (assuming the first 6 are strings, the next 4 doubles for ease of explaining the point), I could;

```
dim myDSstrings(6,10000) as string
dim myDSdoubles(4,10000) as double
```

This gives me back the control and efficiency- but is also a bit clunky (in practise the types are mixed and different- and I end up having an odd number of elements in each one, and end up having to assign them individually in the code- rather than on mass).  So, its a case of;

```
myDSstrings(1,r) = cells(r,1)
myDSdoubles(2,r) = cells(r,2)
myDSstrings(2,r) = cells(r,3)
myDSstrings(3,r) = cells(r,4)
myDSdoubles(3,r) = cells(r,5)
..etc...
```

Which is a lot more ugly than;

```
myDataSet(c,r) = cells(r,c)
```

So- it got me thinking- I must be missing something here.  What is the optimal way for storing an array of different data types?  Or, assuming there is no way of doing it- what would be best coding-practise for storing an array of mixed data-types?

Comment: JMax has an answer for what is probably your real question. For a discussion of the tradeoffs when using variants, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5488314/58845

Comment: You could make an array of arrays, with each contained array being of a specific type.  You should be able to index via BigArray(3)(4) for example.  Dick's comments still apply.

Comment: [**the datatype in variant arrays is auto-adjusted**, *which I understand as if Excel can figure out the DataType for each element it will adjust it automatically as Variant arrays can store elements of different types*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa163618(v=office.10).aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never optimize your code without measuring first.  You'll might be surprised where the code is the slowest.  I use the PerfMon utility from Professional Excel Development, but you can roll your own also.

Reading and writing to and from Excel Ranges is a big time sink.  Even though Variants can waste a lot of memory, this

```
Dim vaRange as Variant
vaRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:E10000").Value
'do something to the array
Sheet1.Range("A1:E10000").Value = vaRange
```

is generally faster than looping through rows and cells.

My preferred method for using arrays with multiple data types is to not use arrays at all.  Rather, I'll use a custom class module and create properties for the elements.  That's not necessarily a performance boost, but it makes the code much easier to write and read.

Comment: Thanks Dick- this is the type of things I was after.  Both the looping and degree of optimisation required are sort of irrelevant in this- the code takes 15 minutes to run and I have a fairly detailed view of which bits are causing the bottleneck (overuse of variants is certainly not the significant cause!).  It was more a generic question; I hadnt thought of using class modules to build properties- I may post a new question on this approach depending on what resources I can find.  Many thanks.

Comment: Found this Q that has fairly good example of how it can be done.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161666/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-classes-in-vba

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure your bottleneck comes from the `Variant` typing of your array.

By the way, to **set values from an array to an Excel range**, you should use (in Excel 8 or higher):

```
Range("A1:B2") = myArray
```

On previous versions, you should use the following code:

```
Sub SuperBlastArrayToSheet(TheArray As Variant, TheRange As Range)
  With TheRange.Parent.Parent 'the workbook the range is in
    .Names.Add Name:="wstempdata", RefersToR1C1:=TheArray
    With TheRange
      .FormulaArray = "=wstempdata"
      .Copy
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
    End With
    .Names("wstempdata").Delete
  End With
End Sub
```

from [this source](http://www.avdf.com/apr98/art_ot003.html) that you should read for VBA optimization.

Yet, you should **profile your app** to see where your bottlenecks are. See [this question from Issun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103552/benchmarking-vba-code) to help you benchmark your code.

Comment: And the other way round: `myArray = range("a1:b2")` !!

Comment: `myArray = range("a1:b2").value`