# How do I exclude stuff from gprof output?

Tags: gcc, gprof

I'm trying to profile an application I have, but I don't want anything related to the UI (made in wxWidgets) to show up in gprof's callgraph etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Additional info: I'm on Windows XP, using MinGW gcc and gprof.

Comment: FWIW, I would not be trying to use *gprof* for anything serious. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really going to use it for anything serious. More for getting a sense of what is called often. I'm doing an embedded system which can't be easily profiled, so I was just going to use gprof on the PC to get a sense of where to start measuring for real. Anyway, it seems I can't use gprof since it doesn't work in multithreaded applications on Windows.

Comment: This discusses some of my own experience with embedded systems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890222/analyzing-code-for-efficiency/893272#893272

Answer (score 0):

From the gprof man page:

```
   -E name
          suppresses the displaying of the graph profile entry for routine
          name  (and  its descendants) as -e, above, and also excludes the
          time spent in name (and its descendants) from the total and per-
          centage  time  computations.  (For example, -E mcount and all of
          the other monitor(3) routines are excluded by default.)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I have tried to use this option but it still prints the function.