# Ruby exception trace

Tags: ruby, exception, raise

I have Ruby function, like this:

```
module MyModule
  def function
    raise ArgumentException if true
  end
end
```

Then, I use this function in some another nesting functions just like

```
def upperfunction
   MyModule::function
end
```

So, if i call upperfunction in irb, i want to see full trace like

> line 2 upperfunction.rb
>
> line 3 my_module.rb
>
> ArgumentError

But I get only

> line 3 my_module.rb
>
> ArgumentError

What ahould I do to see full trace?

Comment: Take a look at `caller` as indicated in this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322524/how-do-you-view-a-sample-of-the-call-stack-in-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$@`.  That contains the backtrace of the last exception (the last exception object is in `$!`).

An alternative solution would be to use a better ruby shell, [pry](http://pryrepl.org/), in which you can see backtraces with the `wtf!` command (the more exclamation points, the more of the backtrace will be shown)

Comment: Mb, this is good solution. But why when you use some famous libraries like rack or activerecord you can see full trace of everithing? I want my library to do the same!
Or, I should catch and throw again everithing and everywhere?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I think what's at issue here is that you're calling your method in irb, which suppresses some of the backtrace, whereas rack and activerecord will spit it out all over the place.