# Monitoring the performace of a software that I've created

Tags: java, performance, profiler

I would like to know whether there are any freeware tools available that would take as an input my program and monitor its performance

for example,

how much memory does it take
  how much time does it take for each operation
  how much time does it take for it to open
  how much of the computer's resources it uses in general

is it possible to find something like this?

Comment: What language is your application in? Most languages have profilers

Comment: There are lots of questions here that deal with application performance and benchmarking. You didn't mention what framework/language, which would be required to provide any focused answer. Try searching for `[profiling] [performance]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Analyzing Code for Efficiency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890222/analyzing-code-for-efficiency)

Comment: the application is written in java

Comment: What is your overall purpose? If all you want to do is monitor, use one of the profilers. If you need to make the program as fast as possible, that's a different purpose. The method I and others use *[is this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)*.

Answer (score 2):

The tool you're looking for is called a profiler. There are many. You'll need to pick one that supports your platform (Java, .NET, whatever.)

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE are you using? There is some that comes with a profiler that analyze the code in terms of memory, cpu time and coverage.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for what is called a profiler.

Since you commented your application is written in java, [this site](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers) has a pretty good overview of free open source java profilers.

To quote the site, you could use any of these tools:

- Cougaar Memory Profiler
- JTreeProfiler
- NetBeans Profiler
- JRat
- Extensible Java Profiler
- JMP
- TomcatProbe
- Allmon
- Perf4j
- JBoss Profiler
- MessAdmin
- JMeasurement
- JMemProf
- DrMem
- JAMon API
- InfraRED
- Java Interactive Profiler (JIP)
- Profiler4j
- DJProf
- Stopwatch
- TIJmp
- Appspy
- OKTECH Profiler
- EurekaJ