# Time and performance profiling tools

Tags: time, profiling, profiler, gprof

In a large scale code base, I am instrumenting functions/methods with timers (start and end time). I will be collecting these time logs (similar to what gprof does). I was wondering if there is a tool that I could use for the following:

1. Post-process or data mine these time logs and get useful information like how long a particular method took, how many times it is called, etc.
2. Visualize these timing logs. Is there a standard format that I could produce the timing logs, so that I could take advantage of some open source or commercial UI tools.

Code base: C++, multithreading (windows/linux). However post processing the logs could be in any environment.

Comment: +1 There's another way to do it. You don't have to go timing everything. Check the [*comment from ErikE on this post*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771). Also the [*first comment on this post*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/893272/23771).